# Get real frame after affine transformation

Tags: ios, pdf, quartz-graphics, cgcontext, quartz-2d

The goal is to get real frames in pdf page to identify the searched string, I am using PDFKitten lib to highlight the text that was searched and trying to figure out how to get frames for highlighted text. The core method is next:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, layer.bounds);

    // Flip the coordinate system
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Transform coordinate system to match PDF
    NSInteger rotationAngle = CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(pdfPage);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(pdfPage, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, -rotationAngle, YES);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pdfPage);

    if (self.keyword)
    {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
        for (Selection *s in self.selections)
        {
            NSLog(@"layer.bounds = %f, %f, %f, %f", layer.bounds.origin.x, layer.bounds.origin.y, layer.bounds.size.width, layer.bounds.size.height);
            CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
            CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, s.transform);
            NSLog(@"s.frame = %f, %f, %f, %f", s.frame.origin.x, s.frame.origin.y, s.frame.size.width, s.frame.size.height);
            CGContextFillRect(ctx, s.frame);
            CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
        }
    }
}
```

Size of layer is (612.000000, 792.000000), but the size of s.frame is (3.110400, 1.107000). How can I get real frame from rect that is filled yellow?

Comment: Entire concept of `frame` is meaningless unless transform is identity. Docs are quite clear about this.

Comment: So there is no way to do that? Right?

Comment: I don't know what "do that" means. I don't know what you think you're trying to do; you have not even explained what `s` is! But your _question_ is about `frame`, and `frame` is a purely constructed concept which is not meaningful under a transform.

Answer (score 2):

As Matt says, a view/layer's frame property is not valid unless the transform is the identity transform.

If you want to transform some rectangle using a transform then the CGRect structure isn't useful, since a CGRect specifies an origin and a size, and assumes that the other 3 points of the rect are shifted right/down from the origin.

In order to create a transformed rectangle you need to build 4 points for the upper left, upper right, lower left, and lower right points of the untransformed frame rectangle, and then apply the transform to those points, **before** applying the transform to the view.

See the function `CGPoint CGPointApplyAffineTransform(CGPoint point, CGAffineTransform t)` to apply a `CGAffineTransform` to a point.

Once you've done that you could use the transformed points to build a bezier path containing a polygon that is your transformed rectangle. (It may or may not be a rectangle after transformation, and the only sure-fire way to represent it is as 4 points that describe a quadralateral.)

Answer (score -1):

Please use `bounds` property. Also you have to use `bounds` when create custom layout. It's transform free.

`frame` it's rectangle which defines the size and position of the view in its superlayer’s coordinate system. `bounds` it's rectangle defines the size and position of the layer in its itself coordinate system.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410915-bounds